# Vaadin error handling window doesn't show up when error is thrown

Tags: java, error-handling, vaadin

So my problem is strange. I have an Exception type called `InvalidValueException` extending RuntimeException, no problem so far.
I have an `InvalidValueWindow` extending `VerticalLayout` and implementing `HasErrorParameter<InvalidValueException>`.

I have a text field that I validate with a custom method (not with Vaadin Validators, don't ask why, irrelevant to this question) to check the value on click on a button, and I throw `InvalidValueException` if incorrect. No problems here either, the `InvalidValueWindow` shows up.

Continuing the exercise, I have to update the title of tab. I tried two solutions:

- `HasDynamicTitle` interface and `getPageTitle()` interaction: this one did not even work out on modifying the title, and broke the error management system I just described.
- `getUI().get().getPage().setTitle("New Title");`: this one works on modifying the title, but breaks the error management somehow.

I made sure I did not modify anything between the working version I had before trying those two things. Why does it break the error handling system? I was thinking that maybe the fact that I need to change the screen to show the error handler makes irrelevant the tab name change, so is it even possible to make it work? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I tried to replicate the problem by implementing a HasDynamicTitle in one of the HasErrorParameter error views  of my test application. But it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @TatuLund Thank you for trying. Would you mind providing this code so I can check what is wrong with my implementation? Like with a pastebin or so.